# Signal SIGABRT error while making countdown timer?

Tags: xcode, swift, sigabrt

I am working on a countdown timer for my app that starts counting down from 15.
This is my code:

```
//
//  ViewController2.swift
//  MYP_TruthOrDare?
//
//

import UIKit

class ViewController2: UIViewController {

    var countd = 15

  @IBOutlet weak var Timer: UILabel!
//
//
    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
       Timer.text = String(countd)
//      

        var time:NSTimer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1, target: self, selector: Selector("updateCounter"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
        func updateCounter() {

            Timer.text = String(countd)

            if (countd > 0){

                Timer.text = String(countd--)
                Timer.text = String(countd)

            }

    }
}



        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.


    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


    /*
    // MARK: - Navigation

    // In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        // Get the new view controller using segue.destinationViewController.
        // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
    }
    */

}
```

However, when I run it, as soon as I get to the part with the timer I see the label flash 15 for a second but then it immediately crashes with the SIGABRT error. What can I do?

Answer (score 1):

Generally a timer is added to an NSRunLoop.

```
let myTimer = NSTimer(timeInterval: 1.0, target: self, selector: "updateCounter", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
NSRunLoop.mainRunLoop().addTimer(myTimer, forMode: NSDefaultRunLoopMode)
```

Check the API for other loop modes to suit your needs.

Also, you have your updateCounter function declared within your viewDidLoad()...

Answer (score 0):

As Alex said here. You defined your `updateCounter` function inside `viewDidLoad`, which might cause problems.

Also, always remember to add a `:`(colon) to the selector name.

```
NSTimer(timeInterval: 1.0, target: self, selector: "updateCounter:", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
```

And define your method like this:

```
func updateCounter(timer: NSTimer) {
    // Do something.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem here is that you put your the function your NSTimer calls inside the same function it is in. You have both the NSTimer and the function (`updateCounter`) in viewdidload. To prevent the SIGABRT crash, you must take the `updateCounter` function out of viewdidload.

Here's what your code should be, with **updateCounter outside of viewdidload.**

```
import UIKit

class ViewController2: UIViewController {

    var countd = 15

  @IBOutlet weak var Timer: UILabel!
//
//

func updateCounter() {

            Timer.text = String(countd)

            if (countd > 0){

                Timer.text = String(countd--)
                Timer.text = String(countd)

            }

    }
    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
       Timer.text = String(countd)
//      

        var time:NSTimer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1, target: self, selector: Selector("updateCounter"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

}
}
```